# click on copy button using javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, froala

I am trying to click on copy button on an editor using Javascript for automation purposes but the text not stored in the clipboard

tried the below codes

```
  const button = document.getElementById("copy-1");
button.click();
```

and

```
   const button = document.getElementById("copy-1");
   const event = new Event("click");
   button.dispatchEvent(event);
```

the HTML code

```
<button id="copy-1" type="button" tabindex="-1" role="button" class="fr-command fr-btn" data-cmd="copy" data-title="Copy" style="outline: 1px solid blue;">
    <froalacopy_button class="hoverable"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></froalacopy_button><span class="fr-sr-only">Copy</span>
</button>
```

also, I tried to copy it directly but the copied text was not formatted

[image]

Comment: The JavaScript works fine. The problem is something else .

Comment: [What do you mean by "it doesn't work"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: the formatted text not stored in clipboard

Comment: Please duplicate this https://jsfiddle.net/froala/2L6txyf4/ with your copy button and extra JS so we can see it's not working

Comment: my purpose to add the JS code on the browser console is to press the button and copy the text in the editor not by clicking by mouse

Comment: You might want to read the Froala guide. https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods/#events.trigger

Answer (score 0):

According to Froala Editor you do not need to handle the custom button click event manually. You can add a button using its methods like `DefineIcon` and `RegisterCommand`.

In `RegisterCommand` you will get the `callback` method which will handle the `onclick event` of that button.

```
FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('insert', {NAME: 'plus', SVG_KEY: 'add'});
FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('insert', {
  title: 'Copy the selected text',
  focus: true,
  undo: true,
  refreshAfterCallback: true,
  callback: function () {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
});
```

You can check more from [here](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/custom-buttons/)